# Конвертировать char* в wchar_t*

Tags: c

Как конвертировать char* в wchar_t*? Или записать содержимое первого во второе

Answer (score 3):

Краткий перевод [данного](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8032108/11790859) ответа:

Используйте функцию `mbstowcs(целевая строка, исходная строка, размер)`. Вот небольшой пример для Вас:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    char * x = "Hello";
    wchar_t * y = malloc((strlen(x) + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t)); // +1, чтобы поместился нуль-символ, завершающий строку
    mbstowcs(y, x, strlen(x));

    printf("%ls", y);


    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

P.S. А знаете, как я нашёл это решение? Скопировал в Google Ваш вопрос, ничего не изменяя, и перешёл по первой же ссылке...

Comment: Жаль, что нельзя поставить дополнительный плюсик - за PS ))

Comment: Разве в вопросе стоит метка с++?

Comment: @mik.ov, стоит, но на С++ у меня только пример. Сама функция актуальна и для С.

Comment: Я думаю что ТС и все другие, которые не понимают разницу, будут копировать ваш код, а потом вновь задавать вопросы, почему не работает. Думаю стоит исправить. Вывод широкой строки через `printf` `"%ls"`.

Comment: @mik.ov, Вы правы, поправил.

Comment: только локаль надо установить, прежде чем с широкими символами работать...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, с англоязычными у меня и так работает.

Comment: нуда... s/надо/желательно/... с чем-то за пределами latin-1 результат почти наверняка будет неожиданным...